# Low screen brightness

Tags: grub2, windows, screen, brightness

If I turn on my laptop without charger, my screen brightness is very low, not only in Ubuntu desktop but in Grub too. I've got dual-boot, Windows hasn't got this problem. So can you suggest me any methods to fix this issue?

*NOTE: On my computer doesn't work method with acpi_backlight and modifying Intel configuration file.*

---

Result of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M]
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

Comment: In my case changing the brightness with hotkeys on the keyboard (sun symbol with + and -) when I'm in `grub` help and persists the setting after `grub` loads Linux.

Comment: Yes, but on my computer hotkeys don't work :/

Comment: what's the result of  `lspci`?

Answer (score 0):

try to install intel opensource driver, in most cases it works better https://01.org  and then set acpi backlight and acpi osi to grub, also check this link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight

Comment: I've just installed it, reboot computer, but with no effects :/

Comment: then i dont have any other ideas, i have always tried to combine these solutions, in the end i always got it working.